# Получаю ошибку JQuerry Uncaught ReferenceError: admin is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ошибка происходит в строке <a style='cursor: pointer' onclick 'checkChat(......)'
Uncaught ReferenceError: admin is not defined     at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick.
admin - это имя пользователя берется из массива data[1][i] вывод в консоли работает - значение не нулевое. Оборачиваю его в кавычки чтобы нормально передалось в функцию как тип String. Функция объявлена выше этой. В чем может быть проблема?

```
let id = data[0][i];
let name = data[1][i];
divElement = divElement + "<div class='d-flex bd-highlight'>\n" +
                    "  <div class='img_cont'>\n" +
                    "  <img src='https://filkiniada-4sc.ucoz.org/80781_3.jpg' class='rounded-circle user_img'>\n" +
                    "   <span class='online_icon'></span>\n" +
                    "   </div>\n" +
                    " <div class='user_info'>\n" +
                    " <a style='cursor: pointer' onclick='checkChat(" + id + ',' + '' + name + ''+ ")'>\n" +
                    "   <span>"+data[1][i]+"</span>\n" +
                    "    </a>\n" +
                    "    <p>"+data[1][i]+" is online</p>\n" +
                    "    </div>\n" +
                    "     </div>"
```

Comment: у вас ошибка на js, в браузере. Скидывайте содержимое `checkChat`. Хотя у вас что-то не то с кавычками похоже.

Comment: Вот начало функции checkChat, принимает она id и username в String, все должно корректно передаваться. Сама функция работает без ошибок.                                                                                                                             
        function checkChat(id, username) {
        userId = id;
        userName = username;
        $.get('/chat/messages/${getId}/'+id+'', function (data) {
            $("#chat_with").html('Chat with ' + username)

Comment: Возможно что-то не так с кавычками, но можно ли тогда как-то по-другому передать туда значения?

Comment: Пожауйлста, приводите код в вопросе, а не в комментариях. У вас параметр `name` явно не в кавычках. Попробуйте так `" <a style='cursor: pointer' onclick='checkChat(" + id + ',' + '"' + name + '"'+ ")'>\n"`. Но может появится другая проблема - в значение переменной `name` могут быть кавычки, переносы строк и другие управляющие символы, которые вам все сломают. Поэтому крайне не рекмондуется строить html через строки. Лучше создавайте элементы, навешивайте события через DOM API.

Comment: Благодарю, помогло, значения name у меня фильтруются при регистрации, таких ситуаций возникнуть не может. Спасибо!

Comment: А могут ли в `name` быть символы `& <> /`?. Подобные символы могут также сломать вашу HTML разметку.